# Qt: from a fixed number of bytes to an integer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, byte, qbytearray

Using Qt5.4, I build the function `generateRandomIDOver2Bytes`. It generates a random number and it puts it onto a variable that occupies exactly two bytes.

```
QByteArray generateRandomIDOver2Bytes() {
    QString randomValue = QString::number(qrand() % 65535);
    QByteArray x;
    x.setRawData(randomValue.toLocal8Bit().constData(), 2);
    return x;
}
```

My issue is reverting the so generated value in order to obtain, again, an integer. 
The following minimum example actually does not work:

```
QByteArray tmp = generateRandomIDOver2Bytes(); //for example, the value 27458 
int value = tmp.toUInt(); 
qDebug() << value; //it prints always 9
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you aware that `randomValue` contains the random number in ASCII characters for the decimal digits? That's what [`QString::number()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-2) returns. Obviously, for the range of [0, 65535], this will occupy upto 5 bytes. If you want to store [0, 65535] in two bytes, conversion to string (text) is a bad choice. A `short` (or `std::uint16_t`) (storing it as binary integer) would be much more sufficient, wouldn't it? Then you could read the two bytes of the `short` and store them into the `QByteArray`. (Or, did I misunderstand your intention completely?)

Comment: You are perfectly right. In fact, my problem can be resume in two points:
1- How to convert a std::uint16_t in a QByteArray that occupies exactly two bytes? 
and
2- How to revert the QByteArray and re-obtain the short?

Comment: Thank you for your effort Scheff. I saw the answer of p-a-o-l-o and I am trying to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 16 bit integer can be split into individual bytes by bit operations.

This way, it can be stored into a `QByteArray`.

From Qt doc. of [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details):

> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings.

For recovering, bit operations can be used as well.

The contents of the `QByteArray` does not necessarily result into printable characters but that may not (or should not) be required in this case.

`testQByteArrayWithUShort.cc`:

```cpp
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
  quint16 r = 65534;//qrand() % 65535;
  qDebug() << "r:" << r;
  // storing r in QByteArray (little endian)
  QByteArray qBytes(2, 0); // reserve space for two bytes explicitly
  qBytes[0] = (uchar)r;
  qBytes[1] = (uchar)(r >> 8);
  qDebug() << "qBytes:" << qBytes;
  // recovering r
  quint16 rr = qBytes[0] | qBytes[1] << 8;
  qDebug() << "rr:" << rr;
}
```

Output:

```
r: 65534
qBytes: "\xFE\xFF"
rr: 65534
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the random value 27458, when you do this:

```
x.setRawData(randomValue.toLocal8Bit().constData(), 2);
```

you're filling the array with the first two bytes of this **string**: "27458".

And here:

```
int value = tmp.toUInt();
```

the byte array is implicitly cast to a string ("27"), which in turn is converted to a numeric value (an unsigned integer).

Let's try something different, that maybe suits your need.

First, store the value in a numeric variable, possibly of the deisred size (16 bits, 2 bytes):

```
ushort randomValue = qrand() % 65535;
```

then just return a byte array, built using a pointer to the `ushort`, cast to `char *` (don't use `setRawData`, because it doesn't **copy** the bytes you pass it in, as well explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#setRawData)):

```
return QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&randomValue), 2);
```

To get back to the value:

```
QByteArray tmp = generateRandomIDOver2Bytes(); //for example, the value 27458

ushort value;
memcpy(&value, tmp.data(), 2);
```

Please notice: types do matter here. You wrote an `uint` in a byte array, you must read an `uint` out of it.

All this can be generalized in a class like:

```
template <typename T>
class Value
{
    QByteArray bytes;
public:
    Value(T t) : bytes(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(T)) {}
    T read() const
    {
        T t;
        memcpy(&t, bytes.data(), sizeof(T));
        return t;
    }
};
```

so you can have a generic function like:

```
template<typename T>
Value<T> generateRandomIDOverNBytes()
{
    T value = qrand() % 65535;
    qDebug() << value;
    return Value<T>(value);
}
```

and safely use the type your prefer to store the random value:

```
Value<ushort> value16 = generateRandomIDOverNBytes<ushort>();
qDebug() << value16.read();

Value<int> value32 = generateRandomIDOverNBytes<int>();
qDebug() << value32.read();

Value<long long> value64 = generateRandomIDOverNBytes<long long>();
qDebug() << value64.read();
```

Comment: Thank you p-a-o-l-o. You highlighted some of my weaknesses, but I did learn a lot. I am trying to reproduce it, I let you know soon.

Comment: Dear p-a-o-l-o, the majority seems ok. Unfortunately, printing "value" after:
ushort value;
memcpy(&value, tmp.data(), 2);
Always returns 0. I cannot get why.

Comment: Yes, I well returned an return QByteArray(x); . I still have the issue. However, the solution of Scheff seem to work in my case.

Comment: @JoeMatt I edited the answer again: just return a QByteArray and don't use setRawData at all.

Comment: Thanks p-a-o-l-o! I will reproduce it soon.